# Auto expanding width on div, float or absolute?

Tags: html, css

### The Issue

I have a box which contains dynamic information about the user on my site. As the data is dynamic, the box MUST auto fit to the content. I had no issue getting this to work, as seen in this:

[Example - jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vDgHq/2/).

As you can see, if the content is longer, then the `div#dd_ui` just expands relatively and the elements stay in their correct positions.

Despite the above example working, I would actually like the box to look a little different. I would like the two bottom columns to always be the same width as each other (but resize relatively), and therefore allow for center aligning on their content. In other words, I would like the box to look like this:

[image: User Information Box (new look)]

However, the problem arises when the above content increases, as the footer columns must also expand relatively like so:

[image: User Information Box Expanded (new look)]

### My Question

I cannot think of any good ways to achieve this without using javascript *(which I will not resort to in this case)*. **Can anybody see a good way to achieve this using CSS?**

I thought about using `width:50%;` but this will not work because there is a 1 pixel divider *(most likely a border)* inbetween the two divs.

Everything I have tried has not worked, resultantly I do not really have any code to use as a starting point other than that included in the above jsFiddle. I hope that is enough

Very much appreciate any help :-)

Comment: You could use `width: 50%;` and use an inset border

Comment: @Andy How can I create an inset border? Is it CSS3 or will it work in the older browsers?

Comment: @Andy and also, if the content of the footer boxes is larger then `50%` then I need both boxes to expand (although this is not necessary as I can just specifiy a minimum width worst case scenario)

Comment: Only IE8+ I'm afraid. You would use the `box-sizing: border-box` property.

Comment: @Andy That's what I thought :-(. I have had a play with positioning etc and have come up with http://jsfiddle.net/vDgHq/4/. What do you think of this?

Comment: Doesn't look very nice when resized. I will probably get lynched for this, but a table looks like it would do the job spot on...

Comment: @Andy I thought you might say that about the table haha. My colleague suggested it and he did get lynched :-) Will add my styles to it and it should look nicer when resized as that is actually what I want

Comment: @Andy With styling http://jsfiddle.net/vDgHq/5/

Comment: Try making it smaller, it messes up, you'll need to add a min width

Comment: @Andy How do you mean? I cant see a problem with it at the mo

Comment: If you drag the jsfiddle window divider to make the Results window smaller, it messes up

Comment: @Andy haha, yes you are right, it also looks horrible in IE. Will look into it

Comment: @Andy Fixed with `min-width`, but still problems in IE. Looking into those now. http://jsfiddle.net/vDgHq/7/

Comment: @Andy Managed to fix it in IE 9 using `clear:both;`, but still issues in IE 8 and 7. God I hate IE, why would anyone use it!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try code below:

If line#5 of CSS declarations (`#dd_ui div#top div`) is removed top DIVs will use 50% width, but in this case grows a problem with the top right div content going out of the div.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html><head> 
  <style>
  #dd_ui {position:absolute; top: 10px; left: 10px; padding:0px; border: 1px solid #666; font-family:arial;}
  #dd_ui div {position: relative;}
  #dd_ui div#bottom {border-top: 1px solid #666; max-height: 75px;}
  #dd_ui div div {display: inline-block; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 50%; margin: 0px; vertical-align:top; }
  #dd_ui div#top div {position:relative; width: auto;}
  #dd_ui div#bottom div {border-left: 1px solid #666; margin-right:-1px;}
  #dd_ui div#bottom div:first-child {margin-right: 0px; border-left: 0px;}
  #dd_ui div div p {position:relative; left: 50%; display:block; width: 100%; margin: 0px; margin-left: -50%; padding:0px; border: 2px solid red;}
  #dd_ui div div span {position: relative; display: block; text-align: left; line-height: 100%;}
  #dd_ui div div.right span {text-align: right;}
  #dd_ui_name {margin:20px 20px 0px; font-size:18px; font-weight:bold;}
  #dd_ui_company {margin:5px 20px 10px; font-size:12px; color:#666;}
  #dd_ui_email {margin:23px 20px 0px; font-size:14px; font-weight:bold; width: auto;}
  #dd_ui_ac_number {margin:5px 20px 10px; font-size:12px; color:#666; }
  #dd_ui .title {font-size:12px; color:#666; margin:20px 20px 0;}
  #dd_ui .value {font-size:18px; font-weight:bold; margin:5px 20px 20px;}
  </style>
  </head><body>
  <div id="dd_ui"><div id="top"><div class="left">
        <span id="dd_ui_name">Full Name Here</span>
        <span id="dd_ui_company">Director, Company Name Limited</span>
  </div><div class="right">
        <span id="dd_ui_email">askjdhasjkhasdjkasdhaksjdhaskjdhakjdhaskdj</span>
        <span id="dd_ui_ac_number">Account Number: 5</span>
  </div></div><div id="bottom"><div class="left">
        <span class="title">Last logged In</span>
        <span class="value">09-Nov-2012 15:35</span>
  </div><div class="right">
        <span class="title">Registered With</span>
        <span class="value">2 Companies</span>
  </div><div>
  </body></html>
```

Hope this helps, you can play further.

**UPDATE** - by @BenCarey

The above code is correct, however there are a few issues that cause the cells to wrap when the content is larger then the container. The following jsFiddle contains the correct code to prevent the cells from wrapping.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HUsZW/3/)

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I think I have managed to sort it using this http://jsfiddle.net/vDgHq/8/ If you are able to get it working in IE 8 adn you edit your answer I will happily accept it :-)

Comment: I trust it works in IE8, just use full code I sent you (copy in new html doc and load it in your browser locally) to be sure IE not come to quircks mode.

Comment: The code you have done works in IE 8, but when you resize the window in any browser, the top right cell shifts below the top left cell. In the code that I have done, this is sorted, but there is a small bug in IE 8 that I havent managed to fix

Comment: In my code top right cell come below top left only if you resize window to size which is smaller than required space - which is accurate for such layout.

Comment: This is not what I want though, the top right cell must always be on in the top right, it must never shift below the left cell

Comment: This can be acheived using max-width properity. I trust its better to broke layout instead of hide content for visitors with smaller resolution screens, but you vision is probably different. 

Good luck!

Comment: Your answer is right, I have just made a few edits to your CSS and html, as there were a few pointless bits of code in there. I fixed the wrapping issue by adding `white-space:nowrap;` to the `.content` div. Thanks for your help, will accept your answer once my edits to it are accepted by the reviewers :-)